# How to clear the AttributeError for win32com of "object has no attribute 'GetNameSpace'"

Tags: python, outlook

I'm trying to download emails and pdf attachments for a certain time range but when trying to run it in Python, I'm receiving the error: "AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library._Application instance at 0x1796763072736>' object has no attribute 'GetNameSpace'"

It used to work last week but not sure what went wrong with the code since I haven't touched it either. Sharing my entire code below.

```
import win32com.client
import os
import time
import datetime as dt
import re

DateFilter = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days = 2)

#Outlook MAPI
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNameSpace("MAPI")
#Inbox Folder
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
#Download Path
path = os.path.expanduser("~\\Desktop")
#Sort emails in inbox
messages = inbox.Items
messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)
#Filter emails to go through
DateFilterMsg = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + DateFilter.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')+"'")

for message in DateFilterMsg:
    #Saving pdf attachments and their emails
    for attachment in message.attachments:
        if attachment.FileName.find(".pdf") > -1:
            attachment.SaveAsFile(f"{path}\\Email Downloader\\attachments\\{attachment.FileName}")
            emailname = str(message.subject)
            emailname = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', ' ', emailname)
            print(emailname)
            mailName = f"{path}\\Email Downloader\\emails\\{emailname}.msg"
            message.SaveAs(mailName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question to have it closed

```
GetNameSpace = GetNamespace
message.attachments = message.Attachments
mesasge.subject = message.Subject
```

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue. Could you explain what does this answer mean a little further?

Answer (score 0):

please as Edward mentioned, try the following:

```py
import win32com.client
import os
import time
import datetime as dt
import re

DateFilter = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days = 2)

#Outlook MAPI
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
#Inbox Folder
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
#Download Path
path = os.path.expanduser("~\\Desktop")
#Sort emails in inbox
messages = inbox.Items
messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)
#Filter emails to go through
DateFilterMsg = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + DateFilter.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')+"'")

for message in DateFilterMsg:
    #Saving pdf attachments and their emails
    for attachment in message.Attachments:
        if attachment.FileName.find(".pdf") > -1:
            attachment.SaveAsFile(f"{path}\\Email Downloader\\attachments\\{attachment.FileName}")
            emailname = str(message.Subject)
            emailname = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', ' ', emailname)
            print(emailname)
            mailName = f"{path}\\Email Downloader\\emails\\{emailname}.msg"
            message.SaveAs(mailName)
```